# Import a mathematical function from a csv file with genfromtxt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array from a .csv file in which the second column is filled with different functions to calculate shear sections.

When I try to import the .csv file, every single row from that column that contains a function (eg. 188*x**2) it returns as a nan in python.

```
import numpy as np 
filename = 'filename_for_functions.csv'
data = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter = ',', skip_header = 1)
```

and it returns as an array with nan values in some parts

is there another way to import a csv file and use any functions from 
the 'data':

```
array([[   0.    ,    0.    ,    0.    ],
       [   5.9   ,       nan,       nan],
       [   6.9   ,       nan,       nan],
       [  10.8   , -145.02  ,       nan],
       [  23.5   , -130.52  ,       nan],
       [  23.5   ,       nan,       nan],
       [  35.25  ,  130.53  ,       nan],
       [  46.75  ,  145.03  ,       nan],
       [  58.5   ,       nan,       nan],
       [  71.2   ,       nan,       nan],
       [  75.1   ,    0.    ,   -0.3699]])
```

Every single 'nan' is a function in the .csv file that i want to use to calculate something else in the code

The code will pull a mathematical function from the excel file, and it will calculate the shear in that position with the mathematical formula from the .csv file. I know it would be easier to hard code the formulas in an array in the code but I want it to be more flexible.

Didn't find anything in google

EDIT:

I used the dtype advice to solve this issue. but it returned with a weird issue that didn't help me at all. What I did do was turn every value into a string, then when called I would turn them into python readable line with eval(). for the numbers i use float() ( int() can also be used i guess). be aware of what your values are, because maybe you may need them to stay as strings.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter = ',', skip_header = 1, dtype= str)
```

Almost forgot to say this is solved, and here is my solution.

Comment: Please include that result array in the post itself, not as an image. Can you include at least part of the data file, as well as an explanation of what you’re trying to do? See: [mcve].

Comment: Show a sample file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks problem with dtype

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'filename_for_functions.csv'
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter = ',', skip_header = 1, dtype=None)
```

If dtypes are `None`, then columns will be determined by the contents of each column, individually.

You can read about dtype here https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html

Comment: used the dtype advice to solve this issue. but it returned with a weird issue that didn't help me at all. What I did do was turn every value into a string, then when called I would turn them into python readable line with eval(). for the numbers i use float() ( int() can also be used i guess). be aware of what your values are, because maybe you may need them to stay as strings.

data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter = ',', skip_header = 1, dtype= str)
Almost forgot to say this is solved, and here is my solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If there was an example of an incoming CSV file and an example of the expected output, then I could offer a more suitable solution for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays support one data type, e.g. int64. You can import your csv file using Pandas dataframe which supports different data types for each column:

```py
import pandas as pd
filename = 'filename_for_functions.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
```